# Database Architecture: Storing time or distance in one column

Tags: sql, database-design, decimal

This is a different question then [sorting by time or distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962998/sorting-a-string-that-could-contain-either-a-time-or-distance).

Imagine a table storing track & field results.  A result for a running event would be in seconds and a field event would be in meters.  What is the proper way to architect this in a database?

We currently have `athlete_id INT event_id INT result DECIMAL(10,3)`.  We convert times to seconds and store meters as meters.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the data once it is stored? Will you be doing queries that might analyze the differences between multiple events or will this just be a field you display?

Comment: Queries to compare performances - SORT ASC, MAX, etc.  After returning a result, the field is then transformed via calculation to a pretty display.  We currently have 1 more field I forgot to include `result_display VARCHAR` which is the pretty print version of result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to architect this is to stop thinking about entering data and start thinking about how you intend to use the data. If all you are going to do is to display the results, then storing it in an nvarchar field including the measurement is fine. Optimize for reporting whenever you are thinking something may need calculations.  If it takes an extra quarter of a millisecond to add additional information to the database to make reporting easier, that beats taking additional minutes/hours to query the multi-million record tables and do calculations on all the records every time.

If you want to do calculations, or compare results for different competitions or events, then you need to think about the easiest way to store that data so that you can do the calculations.

What you don't want to do in this case is have to perform any conversions in reporting. Any conversions you need to perform should be when you insert the record rather than when you look at a large table of records and do the reporting or analysis querying.

It is generally worth your while in this case to store start time, end time, calculated time and distance in separate fields. Depending on the event, you might need to store multiple records per person. I would separate out timed event and distance events and any events that are based on judges scores (like dressage or ice skating, but I am not sure of Track has any of these types of events) into separate child tables from the original even table because how you want to deal with the information for each type would be different.

If you want to do both, it might be worth your while to simply querying for results with a nvarchar or varchar field and then use separate field to store the results in a calculated form.

Answer (score 2):

That seems fine to me, partly because any comparison or aggregation -- max, min, avg -- of values is only going to be valid in the context of a particular event type anyway.

I'd assume that there would be another value to indicate the units in which the value is stored for that event, or event type.

You'd probably want to store scores as well as distances and times also, I guess.

I'm not convinced about displaying a pretty value also, because you might want to internationalise that or present it in different formats or units. It might be calculated on demand.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use separate columns for different measures: `time DECIMAL(10,3) distance DECIMAL(10,3)`.